# Dropbox core api user limit up to 100

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am new in android development as well as working with Dropbox API .in my application user will be connected more then 100. i applied for production last day .so my application status converted to "in review"  but today it converted in "development" .

i read some where that if status converted " production" then after connect with more then 100 users .but in my case status converted to  "development".
so will  Dropbox provide me to connect more then 100 users ?? or i should again apply for production??
my application is not live currently but i tested with 3 accounts so current user is 3/100.
my application is not live is it so status converted to "development" ??
??
I am so much in confusion please help me.

thanks.

Comment: If you applied for production, but your status reverted back to development, it means your app was declined. Every production request will receive a response via email though, so check the email account (including your spam folder) for the email address registered to your Dropbox account. It should contain more information. Generally, it's just a small issue you can fix and then re-apply.

Comment: yes i got mail and i didn,t provide link of my app's so its declined

Comment: Ok, sounds like you can just re-apply and provide the requested information then.